# Изменение ссылочных переменых

Tags: c#, классы

такой вопрос если мы приравняем ссылочные переменные классов и изменим ту, адрес которой хранит другая, то другая не изменится.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        Class1 class2 = new Class1();
        Console.WriteLine("Init");
        Console.WriteLine("Class1.x = "+class1.x);
        Console.WriteLine("Class2.x = " + class2.x);

        Console.WriteLine("=");
        class1.x = class2.x;
        Console.WriteLine("Class1.x = " + class1.x);
        Console.WriteLine("Class2.x = " + class2.x);

        Console.WriteLine("Change");
        class2.x = "Krung";
        Console.WriteLine("Class1.x = " + class1.x);
        Console.WriteLine("Class2.x = " + class2.x);
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string x = "kek";
}
```

Но если мы приравняем сами объекты, то при изменении одной изменится и другая, почему так?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 class1 = new Class1();
            Class1 class2 = new Class1();
            Console.WriteLine("Init");
            Console.WriteLine("Class1.x = "+class1.x);
            Console.WriteLine("Class2.x = " + class2.x);

            Console.WriteLine("=");
            class1=class2;
            Console.WriteLine("Class1.x = " + class1.x);
            Console.WriteLine("Class2.x = " + class2.x);

            Console.WriteLine("Change");
            class2.x = "Krung";
            Console.WriteLine("Class1.x = " + class1.x);
            Console.WriteLine("Class2.x = " + class2.x);
        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public string x = "kek";
    }
```

Comment: Чем отличаются эти 2 куска вставленного кода?

Comment: в одном переменные классов прираниваются, в другом сами обхекты

Comment: в первом случае ты меняешь ссылку на объект, во втором - изменяешь свойство объекта. При смене ссылки, очевидно, никак не задействуется сам объект.